# Transparent background in loaded images PNG - AS2

Tags: flash, png, actionscript-2, flash-8

This could be an old matter. Reading Flash 8.0 Help I've pasted this code and check in runtime

```
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 80, false, 0x00FFFFFF);
var mc:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("mc", this.getNextHighestDepth());
mc.attachBitmap(myBitmapData, this.getNextHighestDepth());
```

and it's ok. Changing false to true, the white rectangle is not seen as expected. I want that property to be applied in my library image called "Airplane" as IDlinkage, so, I added to the previous code the following line:

```
myBitmapData.loadBitmap("Airplane");
```

but when testing scene, it's shown this message : **Error** Static members can only be accessed directly through classes. My idea is to set white background image as transparent color. The image loaded to library is a PNG type and it has already transparent background but Flash ignores this, so I must set that with code. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Image Loader Component in Flash 8.0 solves the question :-/, it load the image with its properties, among them, the alpha channel settings.